# What is the best solution to avoid inline onClick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code I modified and they have inline scripts in HTML.

For an example, in my documents there are few buttons like this.

```html
<button class="btn-primary" onclick="selectAll()">All Students</button>
```

How to avoid this inline styling in the best way possible?

Additional Info : I'm using query files. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use native Js, [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). If you want to use jQuery, then [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: don't write them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the modern, standards-based **[`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** method to configure your event handlers.

```js
// Get your element reference
var btn = document.querySelector("button.btn-primary");

// Configure an event handler.
// NOTE: You don't invoke the function here so no () after the function name
btn.addEventListener("click", showAll);

// This is the callback function
function showAll(){
  console.log("You clicked the button!");
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-primary">All Students</button>
```

Or, in JQuery, use the **[`element.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method:

```js
// Get your element reference
var $btn = $("button.btn-primary");

// Configure an event handler.
// NOTE: You don't invoke the function here so no () after the function name
$btn.on("click", showAll);

// This is the callback function
function showAll(){
  console.log("You clicked the button!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-primary">All Students</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This minimized my code a lot.

Comment: Hi Scott Marcus, Sorry to bother you again. Could you please tell me how can I use this same code of yours for dropdown menu button and it's items. I can start a new question.

Comment: @RashmiNimesha It's no different at all. Just use `.addEventListener()` or `.on()` (depending on whether you want to do it with vanilla JavaScript or JQuery) with any element you need to and use `"click"` when you want to handle clicks, `"change"` when you want to handle value changes, or any other event that you need to.

Comment: I tried to do this using your same code but didn't work for menu items. If possible could you please answer my new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067652/turn-inline-onclick-to-click-jquery/50067772#50067772.

Comment: @RashmiNimesha That's not the correct way to make a custom drop down list. All that is is a group of links, but you're not using them as links, so you shouldn't be using `a` at all. You should make an unordered list (`<ul><li></li></ul>`) and set up `click` event handlers with `.addEventListener()` for each of the `li` elements.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it again using these. I just took that code from one of bootstrap example.

Answer (score 0):

you can set id for button like

```
<button class="btn-primary" id="btn">All Students</button>
```

then create separated js file "script.js" and write in it this

```
window.onload = function(){
var btn = docuemtn.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   selectAll();
});
}
```

to link js file to html file write at the bottom of html file this

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for trying to help! (I did NOT downvote).  This approach is more complex than it needs to be - no need for an ID, necessarily, and no need for an external JS file.

Comment: Also, you are using an event property (`onload`) while trying to teach `.addEventListner()` and you misspelled `document`.

Comment: it is the best practice to separate logic layer from presentation layer. and I set id for button because it may be there are other buttons with this class so that you should identify element with id . window.onload to ensure dom tree is loaded and button become true

Comment: Event properties like `.onload`, etc. (while valid) are not recommended. Use `window.addEventListener("DOMContentloaded")`, especially since your are trying to show `.addEventListener()` in the first place. Or, better yet, skip that particular event binding altogether and just place your `script` just prior to the closing `body` tag. Also, the use of `id` as your first choice to identify an element will eventually come back to haunt you because your HTML will be loaded up with extra attributes and your CSS will become difficult to maintain as `id` based selectors are hard to override.

Comment: Also, placing scripts into their own `<script>` element and including them in an HTML file is still considered separation of concerns. While, it's true that a separate file is desirable for many reasons, it's not something to just use in all cases. A script that is unique to a single page *should* be included in that page IMHO. ;)

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Thanks for helping. Really appreciate this.