# Turn Inline OnClick to Click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following inline styles for a dropdown menu list. I do not know how to make it in to 'click' using jQuery.

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary mw" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret">Subject</span></button>
  
  <div class="dropdown-menu">

     <a class="dropdown-item Business" onclick="selectBusiness()"> Business</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item ICT" onclick="selectICT()"> ICT</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item Arts" onclick="selectArts()"> Arts</a>

  </div>
```

More information:

I tried to do this following code for a button and it's working fine. But as I said I do not know how to make it work for a dropdown menu.

```html
var btn = document.querySelector("button.selectAll");
btn.addEventListener("click", selectAll);
....
```

Your input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery, you can add listener to the classes of each `<a>` inside your dropdown.

```
$(".Business").on('click', function() {
//selectBusiness() or your code here
});

$(".Arts").on('click', function() {
//selectarts() or your code here
});

$(".ICT").on('click', function() {
//selectICT() or your code here
});
```

Another solution would be to add a single listener for all your dropdown-items and then checking the content of the selected one.

```
$(".dropdown-item").on('click', function() {
    switch ($(this).text()) {
        case "Business": 
        selectBusiness();
        break;


    }

});
```